# How to restore multiple in app purchases?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, restore, in-app

I have seen a million posts about restoring in app purchases but I can not find anything about multiple in apps. I am trying to find a way to restore in apps but only if the user has purchased them. Currently it will restore all even if it wasn't ever purchases.

```
 @IBAction func inAppRestoreBtn(_ sender: Any) {
     SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I always thought `restoreCompletedTransactions` was meant for **non-consumable** IAP. Are you asking about consumable IAPs? It doesn't really make sense to restore those. I always thought those fall under the phrase "buyer beware". Now, if your app actually has both.... I'd guess you need to check through each and every IAP receipt. (Ouch!)

Comment: I was under the same impression. It is only non-consumable purchases.